# Modulation Index of an AM wave

Tags: waves, electronics, radio-frequency, radio

I have been given a question as

**RMS value of an *RF*(Radio Frequency) voltage after amplitude modulation to a depth of $50$% by a sinusoidal voltage is $80$ *Volts*. Calculate the RMS value of modulated voltage when modulated to a depth of $75$%.**

Now my question is that, If the modulation index$(m_a=\frac{V_m}{V_c})$ of an AM wave changes, what can be the reason? Will it be due to the change in the carrier voltage or due to the change in modulating voltage? I have proceeded like as $$P_t=P_c\left (1+\frac{m_a^2}{2}\right )$$ and also power is directly proportional to the voltage$(V_{rms})$ squared, therefore we get $$\frac{V_{rms}^2}{2}=\frac{V_c^2}{2}\left (1+\frac{m_a^2}{2}\right )$$ and I got two equations as $$(80)^2=V_c^2\left (1+\frac{(0.5)^2}{2}\right )\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:...(1)$$

$$V_{rms}^2=V_c^2\left (1+\frac{(0.75)^2}{2}\right )\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:...(2)$$On solving the above two, I got the required voltage $$V_{rms}=85.04\: V$$I have assumed that the change in the modulation index is not due to the change in the carrier voltage and kept the both $V_c$ same in both the equations and got the answer but I am still not sure that whether I am correct or not.

Is it the case that the modulating voltage is constant and the modulating index change is due to the change in carrier voltage? And obviously, then the answer will be different.

I am not sure, please explain it. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The carrier signal is assumed not to change but the total or actual transmitted signal does vary of course and it is due to the modulation of the amplitude for AM. The modulation voltage refers to any change that the actual voltage shows relative to the original carrier when no information is being sent. Note the amplitude of the transmitted wave will only change slowly with a much lower frequency than the carrier.
Also note If the operator kept changing the “carrier” voltage by twiddling the knob by hand that would be sort of similar to a radio message except it would be of much lower frequency than typical transmitted radio sounds like music or speech. Hope this helps somewhat.